# CefSharp fails to download css due to mime type mismatch

Tags: mime-types, cefsharp

I'm trying to implement CesSharp for browser support inside of a Winform/WPF application and running into an issue getting the styles to apply on the page. I'm able to embed the browser into the page, but the styles are completely missing. When I check the log file, I see that they were blocked due to a strict MIME checking, but am unsure where I should go to intercept that check.

`"Refused to apply style from 'https://example.com/styles/ig_panel.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.", source: https://example.com/myPage.aspx (0)`

If I browse to myPage in the example, above I see that the type is showing as css not html, so I'm not sure where the incorrect MIME type is coming from. Is this something that can be addressed from the CefSharp RequestHandler or does it require changes on the server?

UPDATE: It appears that the css request in question when accessed through CefSharp is getting a http 405 causing the mime type to come out as text/html instead of text/css. Now to determine what's causing the 405.

Comment: What version are you using? How are you checking the mimeType? How does Chrome behave? What server are you using? CEF doesn't currently provide a means for modifying the response (issue https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2785/allow-modification-of-response-in), whilst you can possibly hack around it, I'd be making sure the server is sending the correct Content Type header first.

Comment: I'm not explicitly checking the type and it loads with text/css in chrome. This is using IIS on the server

Comment: Additionally, It appears to render correctly in Chrome and embedded WebView2 (Edge/Chromium).

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Is the Content-Type header set as expected? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type is the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options header set? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#mime_sniffing